# Why does a source code analyzer claim a NullPointerException could be thrown despite a check for null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm looking at some code I just inherited and ran through a source code analyzer. It points out that I'm at risk of a NullPointerException here:

```
if(!(strLineData == null) && !(strLineData.isEmpty()))
```

While that clearly is a stupid way of testing a String (and it's done all over the place!), why would a NullPointerException be thrown? If strLineData is null, it won't evaluate the second half of the if-statement, right?

Comment: But if strLineData is null, the "!" makes the left side false. Right???

Comment: Maybe the tool isn't looking at short circuiting?

Comment: Try simplifying the statement, e.g. `if(strLineData != null && !strLineData.isEmpty())` and see what your analyzer says.

Comment: Which source code analyser?

Comment: @radoh Exactly. Clearly the redundant parentheses etc. are overloading the apparently limited capabilities of the analyser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. It seems the tool may be bugged as this is mentioned by the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23):

> The conditional-and operator && is like & (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is true.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I wasn't crazy. :-)